# Improve performance of a text-search in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that is performing badly and would like to improve it:

```
select top 10 Id, UpdateDate, Source, WordBag
FROM Search.WordBagCurrent with (nolock)
WHERE 
contains (WordBag,'"101*" and "n*" and "croft*" and "ave*"') 
ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC
```

where WordBag is a Column (varchar(351)) not null.

I have tried other ways of redoing this query, such as using containstable:

```
select top 10 a.Id, a.UpdateDate, a.DataSource, a.WordBag
from Search.WordBagCurrent as a
inner join
containstable(Search.WordBagCurrent, WordBag, '"101*" and "n*" and "croft*" and "ave*"')
as key_tbl
on a.ValuationId = key_tbl.[key]
order by a.UpdateDate desc
```

The execution plans for these two queries show that they are almost identical. what else can I do to improve the performance of these queries? I have also tried using the 'top_n_by_rank' in the containstable but we need all of the results.

Comment: Do you have a `FULLTEXT INDEX` on the relevant columns?

Comment: @salient we already have one for this table

Comment: Can you post the actual execution plan?  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: @scsimon sure, thanks. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJCK2F0te